# How to display newly sorted integers?

Tags: java, sorting

I am doing a project in which the user enters a number, x ,it will then generate x amount of random numbers and add them to an arraylist. In one text field, it will display however many random integers are in the array, I then have to make it so in another textfield, it sorts those numbers through a selection sorting. I'm pretty sure I have the code for it right, I'm just not sure how to get the sorted numbers to display on the text field #2. Heres what I have:

```
ArrayList <Integer> Numbers = new ArrayList <Integer>();

....

String input;
int int1,int2 = 0, min = -1000, max = 1000,j, maximum;
input = Input.getText();
int1 = Integer.parseInt(input);


Random number = new Random();

    while(int2 < int1){
for (int i = 0; i < int1; i++){  
    int randomInt = number.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
    Numbers.add(randomInt);
     int1--;
}
    }
if(Selection.isSelected() && Ascending.isSelected()){
    for (int i = 0; i<Numbers.size()-1; i++){
        maximum = i;
        for(j = i+1; j<=Numbers.size()-1;j++){
            if(j < i){
                int temp = i;
                i = j;
                j = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

     Output1.setText("Unsorted Numbers " + Numbers);
     Output2.setText("Sorted Numbers " + //what here? );
     Numbers.clear();
```

Thanks for any help you might be able to offer.

Comment: When you're sorting, do you want to compare `j < i`, or do you want to get two numbers from your `Numbers` list and compare those?  It looks like your sort doesn't even look into the `ArrayList` that you went to so much trouble to create.

Comment: P.S. The Java standard naming convention is that variable names like `Numbers` should start with a lower-case letter; names starting with upper-case letters are for class names like `ArrayList` or `String`.

Comment: ahh yes, i forgot that

Answer (score 0):

what about this ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //min and max value
    int min = -1000;
    int max = 1000;

    //collection to store numbers
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Random random = new Random();

    //receive input
    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numberFromUser = Integer.parseInt(myScanner.nextLine());
    for (int i = 0; i < numberFromUser; i++) {
        numbers.add(random.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min);
    }

    System.out.println("Unsorted :" + numbers);

    // sort the numbers
    Collections.sort(numbers);
    System.out.println("Sorted   :" + numbers);

    numbers.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should prepare a string:

```
String sortedNumbersOutput = "";
for (int i = 0; i < sortedNumbers.size(); i++) {
    sortedNumbersOutput += sortedNumbers.get(i) + (i != sortedNumbers.size() - 1 ? "," : "");
}
Output2.setText("Sorted Numbers " + sortedNumbersOutput );
```

On a separate note, I don't believe you are sorting your list...

You are comparing on the indices and not the values at those indices.

Maybe you want to try:

```
boolean changes = true;
int temp;
while (changes) {
    changes = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < Numbers.size()-1; i++){
        if (Numbers.get(i) > Numbers.get(i+1)) {
            temp = Numbers.get(i);
            Numbers.set(i, Numbers.get(i+1));
            Numbers.set(i+1, temp);
            changes = true;
        }
    }
}
```

which is called a [bubble sort](http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/bubble-sort)